# Segfault occurring when using erase on a vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, stdvector

I'm writing some basic neural network tools for a larger scale project I'm working on.

the neural network itself is made up of vectors of different structs and for one function I want it to delete a neuron from a specified layer. Whenever I use the function it works correctly until it removes the neuron's edge that go to the neurons into the next layer (layer+1) which is causing a segfault.

```
void NeuralNetwork::deleteNeuron(int t_layer, int t_neuronToDelete){
  if(t_layer < 0 || t_layer >= neuralNetwork.size())
    throw LayerDoesNotExistException();

  int numOfNeurons = neuralNetwork[t_layer].neurons.size();
  if(t_neuronToDelete < 0 || t_neuronToDelete >= numOfNeurons)
    throw NeuronDoesNotExistException();
  //delete neuron

//removes neuron
neuralNetwork[t_layer].neurons.erase(neuralNetwork[t_layer].neurons.begin() + t_neuronToDelete);

//remove its edge from neurons to the right
  if(t_layer != neuralNetwork.size())//doesnt let it remove edges if its the output layer
    for(int i=0; i < neuralNetwork[t_layer+1].neurons.size(); i++){
      std::vector<double*>::iterator it = neuralNetwork[t_layer+1].neurons[i].pWeights.begin() + t_neuronToDelete;

      //this line segfaults
      neuralNetwork[t_layer+1].neurons[i].pWeights.erase(it);
    }
}
```

Comment: `t_layer != neuralNetwork.size()` That test doesn't look right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if(t_layer != neuralNetwork.size())` check will always be true, because `t_layer` is less than `neuralNetwork.size()` (if it wasn't, the previous line's access to `neuralNetwork[t_layer]` would result in Undefined Behavior).

You probably meant to check

```
if (t_layer + 1 != neuralNetwork.size())
```

Comment: Great catch! Unfortunately, though it is still segfaulting.

Comment: @AlexCrim Does every neuron's `pWeights` object have the same number of neurons?  Possibly the calculation of `it` is returning `pWeights.end()` or even past the end of whatever container that is.  You should use your debugger to see the program state at the time of the crash and work from there to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: That was it! pWeights was not sized accordingly so it was immediately out of the container. Thanks for all the help.